# Read/Write/Modify using single semaphore C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, semaphore

I have three threads that enters three different methods doing different jobs on a stringarray.

First one writes to the stringarray.
Second one modifies the string that was written if it meets a certain criteria.
Third one reads the string that has been written and possibly modified.

The whole point is to figure out how to use a single semaphore for this. Problem is that i cant figure out how to synchronize three threads on a single semaphore. In my head it looks like this:

```
Semaphore sem = new Semaphore(0, 1);

string[] stringArray = new string[20];

string replaceString = "Foo";

public string MethodRead(int index)
{
sem.WaitOne();
string temp = strArr[index];
sem.Release();
return temp;
}

public void MethodWrite(string stringToWrite, int index)
{
sem.WaitOne();
stringArray[index] = stringToWrite;
sem.Release();
}

public void MethodModify(int index)
{
sem.WaitOne();
if(stringArray[index] == replaceString)
stringArray[index] = "Bar";
sem.Release();
}
```

I loop through these methods 20 times from each individual thread. Problem is that this makes no sense since there are no orders for the semaphore. I have tried using booleans and a status enum but with no luck. Any one got any guidance?

Comment: What is that you are trying to achieve? can you post the code of the threads? A semaphore is used to control the amount of threads working on a particular place at a given moment, so it seems not to be what you need to use from what I could understand

Comment: Its an assignment for school that im stuck on. The goal is to get a good understanding of how semaphores work and im following the structure i was given. The threads are basically just going through loops that calls for each relevant method. I have a list full of strings in my write class that I want to write to my string array. Then I want to modify the string depending on what its value is. Then read it to get a list full of the correct ouput in my reader class.

Comment: so each thread will call the 3 methods in order? or each thread will call one of those methods independently?

Comment: Independently, these methods are in a class that they all share the same instance of. Its up to this class to synchonize it and make them wait for eachother.

Comment: The classical solution to this would be to have a semaphore for each thread except the first one. The writing thread would just work unobstructed, but release with the semaphore of the modifying thread each time it finishes an item. The modifying thread waits on its own semaphore, but releases on that of the reading thread. The reading thread waits on its own semaphore, but doesn't release anything. I don't see how you could do it with a single semaphore. Semaphores don't care about the order in which waiting threads are allowed to enter the critical section.

Comment: Aaah that makes so much sense! I suppose thats what my teacher wants since the one semaphore case didnt really make sense. Ill try that, thanks :)